# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator' to 'Google.Apis.Http.IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer'

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use google drive services with flowing code and authentication

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
clientId: xxxxxxxx
scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
redirectUrl: new Uri ("myredirect:oob"));
```

and trying to initialize the google drive services by

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
HttpClientInitializer = auth,
ApplicationName = "Google Drive API Sample",
});
```

but above code shows an error
Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator' to 'Google.Apis.Http.IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)